# How can I get all the files from one git branch, and put them into the current branch without merging?

Tags: git

I don't want to commit anything.  I just want to take all the files from a different branch and replace all the current files I'm working on with those, while it doesn't change my current branch at all, essentially like a merge, but without creating that merge state.

The end result would be the same as checking out a different branch, copying the files, then going back to original branch, and just pasting on top of them.

EDIT:
I tried merging the branch into the working tree so it was in the merge state, then doing a git reset originalbranch, and that nearly worked, but it left all the conflicted files with the diff comments...

EDIT2:
Just realized I was on SU and not SO...

Comment: Why? What is your goal?

Comment: I have a base branch.  It's forked with every project.  Throughout the project I've updated some of the base files.  I don't know/care which commits (they're bundled with many other irrelevant changes), but I want to look through the final project files diffed with base and choose what I want to commit to the base individually, file per file.

Comment: Would a code audit or file comparison between base and project identify the changes? Then you could commit those files back to base, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That's basically what I'm going for trying to get the project files into the base branch. There are hundreds of changes in many different files.  I want to hand pick them, they aren't only from individual commits, and some are just pieces of commits.  I use smartGit and it will give me the files modded, I just need to get them into the working tree.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
git merge otherbranch --no-commit --no-ff -X theirs
git reset currentbranch
```

"-X theirs" is needed since "--strategy=theirs" isn't a valid strategy.

"--no-commit --no-ff" prevents the merge from going through just leaving the files in the working tree

And the reset cancels the merge state, but leaves the files.

Comment: `-X theirs` is *not* the opposite of `--strategy=ours`. The two options do very different things. The question is asking for the functionality of `--strategy=theirs`, but your answer does not provide that. What your answer does it tell git to try and automatically merge all files from *otherbranch* into *currentbranch*. If and only if there are conflicts will the files from "theirs" be peferred. But after doing this type of merge `git diff otherbranch currentbranch` will still show lots of changes. See my answer below for an alternative.

Comment: Simpler solution by @BrianHVB `git checkout otherbranch .` works perfectly for me

Answer (score 12):

> The end result would be the same as checking out a different branch, copying the files, then going back to original branch, and just pasting on top of them.

#### Option 1

This is exactly the case for `checkout`. We tend to think that *checkout* is only used to get a branch to work on, but it can also be used to replace files in a current branch. Assuming that you want to replace the contents of `currentbranch` with the contents of `otherbranch` (e.g. copying all files of otherbranch and pasting them to currentbrach), then

```
git checkout currentbranch
git checkout otherbranch .
```

The command says checkout all files (.) from otherbranch and put them on top of currentbranch. Note, that unlike the copy/paste analogy, this will also remove any files in currentbranch that are not present in otherbranch. The downside is that you will lose all of the commit histories from *otherbranch*.

#### Option 2

The below sequence will:

- List item
- make the contents of *currentbranch* identical to *otherbranch*

  - e.g. `git diff currentbranch otherbranch` will show no changes
- preserve the commit history of (*otherbranch* commits will be added to *currentbranch*)
- show the change as a merge (so that it can be reverted)
- leave *otherbranch* unchanged (skip making a temporary branch if this isn't needed)

```
   git checkout otherbranch
   git checkout -b temp-merge-other
   git merge currentbranch -s ours
   git checkout currentbranch
   git merge temp-merge-other --no-ff
   git diff otherbranch      # no difference
   git log           # commit history from dev is included
   git branch -D temp-merge-other
```

Comment: Option 2 is probably the best way to go when working with a team, because everyone will be able to see the history of file modifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like simply to bring all files from another branch to your working directory, you can simple check them out by using the `checkout` subcommand of git.

```
git checkout target # checkout my local branch
git checkout otherbranch -- .
```

The subcommand `checkout` allows you also to retrive files from another branch. For example `git checkout otherbranch -- file.txt` retrieves `file.txt` from branch `otherbranch`. Using `.` instructs Git to retrieve to full content from the given branch.

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible to `git rebase` your branch. This merges in changes without creating a new merge commit. It only works if there are no conflicting changes between the two branches.